# Dialogflow - Not getting response that is configured in the Fulfillment Inline Editor

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am following the tutorial from: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services-actions-on-google

I have setup the "Name" intent, configured a couple of Training phrases, and also a response. See below.

Training phrases:

1. Do you have a name?
2. What is your name?

Response:
My name is Dialogflow!

Then, I went to the Fulfillment section and enabled the inline editor and pasted the following code:

```
   /**
 * Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')

const app = dialogflow()

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Welcome to my agent!')
})

app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(`I didn't understand`)
  conv.ask(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`)
})

app.intent('Name', conv => {
  conv.ask('My name is Dialogflowwwww!')
})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Then clicked on Deploy.

Then went to the "Name" intent, and scrolled down to the Fulfillment section and enabled the "Enable webhook call for this intent."

Again went to the Fulfillment and clicked on Deploy.

Now, in the test chat window, when I enter "What's your name?", I get the response from the intent - that is - "My name is Dialogflow!"

However, I am expecting the reply from the Fulfillment inline editor code - that is - "My name is Dialogflowwwww!".

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screenshot of the entire Name Intent as you've configured it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the 'Actions for Google console' by clicking the 'google assistant' link in the image shown.
[image: google assistant link]

This is because you have used the 'Actions on google' client library for Google assistant.

https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Remove the response from the "default" response within the intent definition

Comment: Hello, the fulfillment should override the response, removing it is not the solution I am looking for.